# Low Level Biztalk schema creation

Tags: c#, xml, biztalk

I have been using biztalk for a few months now, and have learned the in's and out of basic and intermediate level Project creation. Today however I have noticed something at the Beginner level concepts that I must have missed (schema creation). In a project I created using a Schema named "NewSchema" I created a screen record with id and parentid attributes, msg element, and four records named A-D, which are meant to be elements, but with an attribute named ChildID.

I had originally done this project in a C# program I had written to better teach myself how to iterate through XML elements. Now I have adapted the program to biztalk where I noticed elements cannot have "attributes"? To work around this A-D would have to be records with attributes, then I'd have to make a child element of the same name of the record for each A-D record.
Are elements with attributes possible in biztalk? I'm surprised I have never come across this before.

It'll work if I do this:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://WcfServerProject.NewSchema">
      <Screen ID="ID_0" ParentID="ParentID_1">
        <MSG>MSG_0</MSG>
        <A ChildID="ChildID_0">
        **<A>Hello World</A>**
        </A>
        <B ChildID="ChildID_0" />
        <C ChildID="ChildID_0" />
        <D ChildID="ChildID_0" />
      </Screen>
    </ns0:Root>
```

But can I create my project this way in biztalk?:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://WcfServerProject.NewSchema">
      <Screen ID="ID_0" ParentID="ParentID_1">
        <MSG>MSG_0</MSG>
        **<A ChildID="ChildID_0">
        Hello World
        </A>**
        <B ChildID="ChildID_0" />
        <C ChildID="ChildID_0" />
        <D ChildID="ChildID_0" />
      </Screen>
    </ns0:Root>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow.  Elements absolutely can have Attributes.  Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Johns-305 are you talking from a Biztalk Perspective or XML perspective? I know XML allows attributes with elements, but my question put bluntly is, "is it possible with biztalk".

Comment: Yes, of course BizTalk Schemas can have Attributes.  ID, ChildID, ParentID are all Attributes.  That's why the question is a bit perplexing since you're asking about creating something you already have.

Comment: When Validating the instance it says "The element cannot contain text. Content Model is empty". Given this      `<D ChildID="ChildID_0">D
 </D>`, but works given this     `<D ChildID="ChildID_0" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok My Elements can have attributes and data now after switching "Mixed" to "True".

Answer (score 1):

Try using the generate xsd from well-formed xml function, you will get xsd kind of like this:

```
<xs:element name="A">
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:simpleContent>
 <xs:extension base="xs:string">
 <xs:attribute name="ChildID" type="xs:string" use="required" /> 
 </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```